# Passing instances of objects in C++ class constructors (could not compile)

Tags: c++, constructor, most-vexing-parse

Here's my code

```
class B {
public:
    void bar() {std::cout<<"~";}
};

class A {
public:
    A() {b=B();};
    A(B arg_b): b(arg_b) {};
    void foo() {b.bar();};
private:
    B b;
};


int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo();  // works fine

    A aa(B());
    aa.foo();  // could not compile, but if I comment out this line only, it can compile.
}
```

I got this error message

`error: request for member ‘foo’ in ‘aa’, which is of non-class type ‘A(B (*)())’
     aa.foo();`

I'm a beginner in c++, could some one please explain why this code could not compile? and what is the correct way to initialize a class member by passing in an instance?

Comment: `A a(B()); a.foo();` should fail to compile. Please post real, complete code. [See here for posting guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @M.M thanks for replying, I've edited the code (if you're suggesting that pass by reference cannot take rvalues)

Comment: I'm not suggesting that. Read the posting guidelines link.

Comment: @M.M Hi, I've changed the question (since nobody's answered it yet), could you explain a bit (or throw me a link) why it won't compile? thanks!

Comment: When you're facing compilation errors, it's considered polite to include those errors in the question.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks, I've added the error message

Comment: `b=B();` is useless. Default constructor of B is already called in initialization list.

Comment: @M.M Hi, I have reproduced my initial question, and posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/q/42552832/3041068, would mind taking a look? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A aa(B());` is a function declaration.  So you cannot write `aa.foo()` because you cannot use `.` on a function.

The rule is (approximately) that if code could be parsed as either a function declaration or an object definition, then it is parsed as a function declaration.

Instead you could use `A aa{ B() };` which cannot be a function declaration.

[Also see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work?noredirect=1&lq=1)